# MySQL fetch_assoc() shows 1 less result

Tags: mysql, select, while-loop, fetch

i have a table like below:

```
hub dep
A B
A C
B D
B E
B F
E G
```

i use mysql select to get query and my code is like below:

```
$sql         = "SELECT dep FROM handd WHERE hub='B'";
        $result      = $conn->query( $sql );
        $row         = $result->fetch_assoc();

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["dep"]."<br>";
}
```

but it just gives me result like below:

```
id: E
id: F
```

and i am wondering where is D?

Comment: What do you think the line before the `while` does?

Comment: nothing at all :)

Comment: @SinaNouri Not the blank line, the line with `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $row         = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

This line stores the result of 'B D'. It actually should be:

```
    $sql         = "SELECT dep FROM handd WHERE hub='B'";
    $result      = $conn->query( $sql );

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["dep"]."<br>";
    }
```